# add custom fields in custom taxonomy meta box in wordpress-3.5.2

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy

Unable to add custom fields in custom taxonomy meta box in wordpress-3.5.2.

I have checked solution in various blogs but Unable to solved this problem. I am using wordpress-3.5.2

What I am trying is :-

```
// A callback function to add a custom field to our "adtag" taxonomy
add_action( 'adtag_edit_form_fields', 'adtag_callback_function', 10, 2);

// A callback function to save our extra taxonomy field(s) 
add_action( 'edited_adtag', 'save_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
```

I have tried solution from below link:-

http://www.codehooligans.com/2010/07/07/custom-meta-for-new-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0/ http://sabramedia.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-custom-taxonomies

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-additional-custom-meta-fields-to-custom-taxonomies/

http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-term-or-taxonomy-meta-data

Please refer image where I need to add custom fields:-

[image]

Comment: did you try adjusting priorities ? like `add_action( 'adtag_edit_form_fields', 'adtag_callback_function', 3, 2);`

Comment: No, Let me try.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please guide me.

Comment: http://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/ try this maybe it will help you